# Generators of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ring.

Tags: ring-theory

I read somewhere that $1$ and $x$ are generators of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.
I understand that $x$ is generator because we can take $xx^{-1}=1$ and we can have any polynomial with $1$ and $x$. But why $1$ alone is a generator? I can't get it.

And In other example why $1,x,y$ are generators of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. How I can get $y$ if I use $x$ as a generator?

Comment: You need $1$ AND $x$ , otherwise you cannot build the constant polynomials. Similar, $\mathbb Z[x,y]$ is generated by $1,x$ and $y$.

Comment: What is the smallest (non-unital) subring of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ containing $2$ and $3x$ ?

Comment: Ok, so generator of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is $\{1,x\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your confusion is that you are interpreting "1 and $x$ are generators of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$" as "the set $\{1\}$ is a generating set of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and the set $\{x\}$ is also a generating set of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$". That statement is untrue. The correct inrepretation is "the set $\{1,x\}$ is a generating set of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

(in fact $\{x\}$ is not a generating set either, since $x^{-1}$ is not included in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$).

Similarly, saying that $1$, $x$, and $y$ are generators of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ means that $\{1,x,y\}$ is a generating set.

Comment: Ok ,that makes a lot of sense. I forgot that $x^{-1} \notin \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Thanks a lot.